# Hide Predicates from Trace

Tags: prolog, trace, swi-prolog

Is there a way to hide individual predicates from the trace? In a rule like this:

```
p(<Stuff>) :-
    q(),
    p(<ModifiedStuff>);
    s(),
    p(<ModifiedStuff>);
    p(<ModifiedStuff>).
```

I would for example like to hide `q()` and `s()` from the trace, because I only am interested in the calls to `p()`.
`q()` and `s()` might call a lot of other predicates, which totally cloggs up the trace and makes it hard to find the relevant calls in it.

## edit 1

I have now tried executing from the command line rather than from inside the interpreter and piping the trace to grep for grepping lines containing `p`... but to my disappointment I had to realize when running from the command line, it still opens a prolog shell, so piping the output does not work at all. Only `print` will actually send to the shell running the prolog process.

## edit 2 (output when using trace(p, all))

```
?- trace(shift_reduce, all).
%         shift_reduce/2: [call,redo,exit,fail]
true.

[debug]  ?- shift_reduce([λ,x,x], T).
 T Call: (8) shift_reduce([λ, x, x], _7344)
 T Exit: (8) shift_reduce([λ, x, x], [e, [λ], [v, [x]], [e, [v, [...]]]])
T = [e, [λ], [v, [x]], [e, [v, [x]]]] ;
 T Exit: (8) shift_reduce([λ, x, x], [e, [λ], [v, [x]], [e, [v, [...]]]])
T = [e, [λ], [v, [x]], [e, [v, [x]]]] ;
 T Fail: (8) shift_reduce([λ, x, x], _7344)
false.

[debug]  ?-
```

Comment: If you want to run from the command line and output to a file, did you try using `tee`? (That is, of course, assuming you're using Linux, but you haven't said... I think Windows has an equivalent command)

Comment: You can use [trace/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=trace/2) to trace intresting for you predicates only. Something like `trace(q, +call).`, `trace(p, +call).`.

Comment: You can also debug using spy points instead of trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SWI-Prolog you can use `trace/2` like:

`trace(p, all)` and this will enable information related to p and also this will activate debug mode.

while you're on debug mode you can call:

```
p(<Stuff>).
```

and this will now show information only for p.

Comment: When I do that the only thing I get is `Call: p(<Stuff>) Exit: p(<FinalResult>)`. All the calls inbetween are not shown.

Comment: can you give an example of what `p(<Stuff>).` could be?

Comment: I'm not sure but try to include all the predicates that you want to show with `trace(List_of_your_predicates,all)`, where you can place as the first argument a list with all predicates you want, still if you don't place s,q then will not be displayed...

Comment: but `p` calls `p`.. or rather `shift_reduce` calls `shift_reduce` many times actually. And these calls are not shown.

Comment: Then I don't know...just one more thing in your edited example it fails, so when it shows false. instead of  `enter` you can press `;` to see other answers...I don't know if this is what you're looking but just mention it...

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I was being stupid and had forgotten that I have a proxy clause `p` that calls the actual implementation `p_` predicate.

Comment: Glad to help !!

Answer (score 1):

When you press return in the debugger, the debugger usually **creaps**. The classical apprach is to set spy points what you want to see. And then **leap** from spy point to spy point. Many debuggers provide a leap command.

Here is an example code:

```
p :- q, s, p.
q.
s.
```

When you trace and creap you get the following trace:

```
?- trace.
true.

[trace]  ?- p.
   Call: (8) p ? creep
   Call: (9) q ? creep
   Exit: (9) q ? creep
   Call: (9) s ? creep
   Exit: (9) s ? creep
   Call: (9) p ? creep
   Call: (10) q ?
```

When you debug, use a spy point on p/0 and leap you get the following trace:

```
?- debug.
true.

[debug]  ?- spy(p/0).
% Spy point on p/0
true.

[debug]  ?- p.
 * Call: (8) p ? leap
 * Call: (9) p ? leap
 * Call: (10) p ? leap
 * Call: (11) p ?
```

You can combine the above with the [leash/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=leash/1) directive, so that the debugger doesn't prompt.